# How do I make my screen zoom in and out in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

The code: https://pastebin.pl/view/6f60a32d
I have tried using opengl and tried putting all of the stuff into a surface, and none of them worked

[image]
if anyone have any ideas on how to zoom in my game pls help me

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) to generate a scaled copy of the display [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) after drawing the scene:

```py
zoomed_screen = pygame.transform.smoothscale(screen, (new_width, new_height))
```

*Blit* the zoomed *Surface* on the screen

```py
screen.blit(zoomed_screen, ....)
```